# $ symbol in select query

Tags: sql, excel, select

why are we giving $ symbol in select query?

("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);

I tried retrive data without $ symbol, but it showed error.

so any one clarify me what is the need for $ in Sheet1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL syntax for ODBC and Ole DB is slightly different

`•For ODBC: SELECT "Column Name" FROM "Sheet One$". I.e. excel worksheet name followed by a "$" and wrapped in double quotes.`

`•For Ole DB: SELECT [Column Name] FROM [Sheet One$]. I.e. excel worksheet name followed by a "$" and wrapped in "[" "]" brackets.`

**Odbc connection strings:**

*For Excel 2.0-2003*

`DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=16;DBQ=C:\Invoice.xls;`

*For Excel 2007*

`DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=16;DBQ=C:\Invoice.xls;`

Both Advanced ETL Processor and Visual Import ETL use odbc to connect to Excel

**OLE DB connection strings:**

*For Excel 2.0-2003*

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";`

*For Excel 2007*

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";`

[Source](http://www.etl-tools.com/visual-importer-etl-news/running-sql-against-excel-file.html)